# How do I keep up with the development of gcc?

Tags: gcc, gnu

I have two download sites for the GCC I'm interested in. One is a git repo

```
  git clone git://gcc.gnu.org/git/gcc.git gcc-cilk-src
```

and the other is a svn repo:

```
  svn checkout svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/branches/cilkplus gcc-cilk-src
```

As I understand, gcc switched to Git not long ago. My question is, is the svn branch also updated at the same time? Will `svn update` reflect the git changes as well?

Bonus question (worth an upvote!): How do I keep up with the current development of the branch I'm interested in? Is

```
  http://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git
```

where I should go for current work? Any other hints for me to keep up to date?

Comment: Also, now that I look at it... looks like the git version is the most recent version of gcc, while the svn is a particular branch... still I wonder if the svn reflects the changes made to the git repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your questions can be answered by reading and clicking a few links on the GCC homepage.

> As I understand, gcc switched to Git not long ago.

No, all GCC development is done in [SVN](http://gcc.gnu.org/svnwrite.html), as clearly stated on the [homepage](http://gcc.gnu.org/): *"Our sources are readily and freely available via [SVN](http://gcc.gnu.org/svn.html) and weekly [snapshots](http://gcc.gnu.org/snapshots.html)."*

The Git repo is a [read-only mirror](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GitMirror) of the SVN repo. The mirror is automatically updated with all commits to svn.

Current work happens on the subversion trunk (in Git the `trunk` and `master` branches both refer to the svn trunk.)  Certain larger projects happen in a branch and are then merged to trunk, there's a list of [active development branches](http://gcc.gnu.org/svn.html#devbranches).  Which branch you should follow depends on what you want to follow, but the trunk/master branch in Git is the most likely to be of interest.

> Any other hints for me to keep up to date?

The GCC [mailing lists](http://gcc.gnu.org/lists.html), obviously. Significant changes are discussed on the 'gcc' list and all patches are sent to and discussed on the 'gcc-patches' list.